# Вызов функции макросом #define rasch(name)

Tags: c++, макросы

Есть функции: bool R1() .... R55();
Хочу вызвать их с помощью макроса:

```
#define rasch(name) R##name()
....
rasch(i);
.....
```

Если вместо i подставить число (rasch(23)), то все получается. А если использовать переменную, то прога пытается вызвать функцию Ri(), что и логично.
Вопрос вот в чем, как можно вызвать функцию макросом, с помощью переменной i ?

Comment: Для переменной есть ещё другое решение **template** называется. В отдельных случаях это будет удобнее применять.

Comment: А зачем макрос, а не функция?

Comment: Можно и функцией. Если знаете как это сделать, то буду благодарен.

Answer (score 4):

Макрос - это простая текстовая замена, естественно, что она заменяет текст `i`, а не значение переменной. Препроцессор не имеет представления даже о синтаксисе языка, а уж о том, что находится в переменной во время выполнения - не знает даже компилятор...

Проще всего - создайте массив указателей на функции примерно как

```
typedef viod (*func)();
func f[55] = { R1, R2, ..., R55 };
```

Ну и

```
void rasch(int i)
{
    f[i-1]();
}
```

Comment: прикол в том, что у меня уже есть массив указателей на функции. А теперь представим, что функций не 55, а 1000. и вбивать func f[1000] = { R1, R2, ..., R1000 } не очень то перспективно. Для этой цели я и хочу использовать макрос. 
Что-то типа:
#define rasch(name) R##name
......
int n = 1000;
for (....)
    func f[i] = rasch(i+1);

Comment: О, ты первый, пока я массив указателей объявлял))

Comment: @Andrey, можно каким-нибудь шаблоном инициализировать массив.

Comment: @Andrey, у тебя странная логика :-) в цикле ты и должен бежать по массиву указателей на функции и выполнять их, в этом отношении подход тот же самый, что ты хотел использовать с макросом. А понял, проблема в инициализации этого массива

Comment: @Andrey, или вообще обычным циклом сгенерировать код инициализации массива и скопипастить его в код.

Comment: С помощью цикла , я хочу передать массиву указателей , указатели на функции. А сами указатели на функции сгенерировать макросом.

Comment: Честно говоря, я в таких ситуациях не гнушаюсь написать отдельную программку в 5 строк, и ее вывод скопипастить в свой исходник... Если уж вы руками (руками ли?) создаете 1000 функций `Ri`, то что стоит заодно и внести их в массив? А еще лучше - сделайте функцию `R(i)`, которая будет просто выполнять нужный `i`-й код... Расскажите, откуда берутся эти тысячи функций, pls, и что в них - ну хоть намеком. А то ощущение, что мы опять не о том думаем...

Comment: Руками я уже все внес. Мне принципиально интересно, как это сделать.

Comment: @Harry, скорее всего это изначально существующие аппаратные функции. Судя по количеству и отсутствию в вопросе вопоса об их написании.

Comment: @Harry, эти функции написал я. Это даже не функции, а методы класса. Каждый метод выполняет свой уникальный расчет. В результате выполнения программы я вызываю тот метод, расчет которого мне требуется исходя из данных введенных пользователем. Вызываю я их с помощью массива указателей на методы.

Comment: Тогда, если они написаны вами и являются членами класса, может, стоит подумать о том, как воспользоваться готовой таблицей указателей - vptr? :) Это, кстати, не совсем шутка. А если совсем серьезно - то такое обилие методов говорит о том, что, может, имеет смысл перепроектировать программу?

Answer (score 4):

Никак. Сделай массив указателей на функции и вызывай по индексу.

https://ideone.com/QLgqQ1

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1() { cout << "f1" << endl; }
void f2() { cout << "f2" << endl; }

void (*fs[])() = { f1, f2 };

int main()
{
  for (int q=0; q<2; ++q)
    fs[q]();

  return 0;
}
```